# Проблемы с деплоем через gh-pages

Tags: github

Пытаюсь задеплоить ни гитхаб реакт приложение, 
но когда выполнение задачи доходит до *gh-pages -d build* (строки в в package.json "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
пишет **"gh-pages" не является внутренней или внешней командой;**
После глобальной установки (*npm install gh-pages -g*) ошибка меняется на 
**"Failed to get remote.origin.url (
task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" option).**
Но после настройки удаленного репо 
*"git remote add origin https://blacknumberthree.github.io/business-card*"
приходит уже другая ошибка **fatal: repository 'https://blacknumberthree.github.io/business-card not found** .
Хотя вообще-то сам репозиторий существует (по адресу можно перейти в браузере)
и плюс, в последнем случае установка идет не по пути указаном в package.jsonв строке "homepage", 
а по пути указаном "git remote add" игнорируя полность package.json.
git version 2.23.0. | windows версия 6.1 (сборка 7600)(Операционная система windows 7 максимальная) | node v 10.16.1